# jQuery - detect if a select object has had options added or removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a <select> object on the form.  There are several methods in the app that can add and remove <option>'s to this <select> box.

I would like to detect when this add/remove happens. Not when an <option> has been selected (I know how to do this already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#yourSelectElement").on("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
  // Code here
});
```

Comment: This is deprecated (I know before being wildly supported) use MutationObserver instead.

Comment: This gets what I needed done.  Thanks all for the input.

Answer (score 0):

try with the onChange method $("").onChange(); and this can solve your question

Comment: onchange is an html event attribute, and it's not written with a capital C. Also jQuery .change method with a select works when an option has been selected, which OP specifically said is not needed

Comment: Humm. get this error - Object doesn't support property or method 'onChange'.  Anyway the "DOMNodeInserted" works for what i needed.